# Insert values into a table from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, database, join, insert, foreign-keys

I am trying to insert values into a table from multiple tables,

the tables that i have looks like this.

**Meter_detail**

- meter_id(primary key)
- meter_no.
- meter_name

**Parameter_details**

- parameter_id(primary key)
- parameter_name
- Address

**meter_data**

- time_stamp
- meter_no.
- address
- value

I require a table that looks like below having all the relationships.

**Main_table**

- S_no(primary key and auto increment)
- meter_id(foriegn key)
- parameter_id(foriegn key)
- Datetime
- value

I tried with a query that didn't work ,it just shows query executing ...

```
insert into main_table(meter_id,parameter_id,datetime,value)
select meter_detail.meter_id,parameter_detail.parameter_id,meter_data.Time_stamp,meter_data.value
from meter_data,
meter_detail ,
parameter_detail;
```

How do i do this.
Thanks

Comment: That's exactly how you do it. What doesn't work then?

Comment: can you state the relationship between the tables?

Comment: @JW meter_no. in meter_details = meter_no. in meter_data table and address in parameter_detail table = address in meter_data table but these are not the keys .

Comment: how many records you are inserting in table

Comment: @Fav I don't know when ever i try to run it ,it gets stuck on query executing and then hangs .

Comment: Try with where clause with about 10 records

Comment: you need to give joins to insert values between below tables.

Comment: @vikas meter_data table has around 357509 rows.

Comment: that's the reason, anyways you can create a view for the same, or if there any special reason to do this inserting